# linear regression with Quarter dummy

Tags: r, linear-regression, data-fitting, dummy-data

I am trying to fit a linear regression to the data below

```
Power<-mutate(Power,Year=format(Date,"%Y"),Quarter=quarters(Date),Month=format(Date,"%m"))
head(Power)
       Date    YY    XX  Year    Quarter
2007-01-01     NA     NA 2007      Q1
2007-01-02     NA     NA 2007      Q1
2007-01-03  55.90  71.40 2007      Q1
2007-01-04  55.25  70.75 2007      Q1
```

The model  is

```
lm(YY~XX+as.factor(Quarter,ref="Q1"),data=Power)
```

This works fine. However, it automatically creates three dummies for 3 quarters. Is there any way to include only one dummy, say Q2 in this model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably the most common way to do this is to create a dichotomous variable on the fly with `I()`.

```
lm(YY ~ XX + I(Quarter=="Q2"), data=Power)
```

This includes a binary predictor in the model that's 1 when `Quarter=="Q2"` and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to create new variable with information you need...

```
Power$Q2dummy <- 0
Power$Q2dummy[which(Power$Quarter == 'Q2')] <- 1
lm(YY~XX+Q2dummy,data=Power)
```

However, it is hard to say, because you dont provide your data or even their summary (what is variable Quarter? Factor with 4 states I guess?).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be to use the `ifelse(rule, if TRUE, if FALSE)` command :

**For Example:**

```
Power$Q2dummy <- ifelse(Power$Quarter == "Q2",1,0)
lm(YY~XX+Q2dummy,data=Power)
```